# Convenience way to find providers in Dagger2

Tags: android-studio, dependency-injection, dagger, dagger-2

I've got a very large project and the issue I'm having is that I wish it was easier to find providers.

I have many modules and for the most part they're global modules injected into the object graph at application start. Here is the issue: Let's say I find a property marked with the `@Inject` annotation, then I'd like to be able to instantly find the provider. How can I do that? I am using Android studio 2.0

Comment: This is an IDE question right? What IDE do you use?

Comment: Android studio. Its a child of Intellij. Yes it could be seen as a IDE question, makes sense. I suppose if i keep one module per package it would help to search but what if im using providers from a global module for example.

Answer (score 0):

I see this is tagged Dagger 2 but since it's not specified in the question I'll provide an answer for Dagger 1.

Square offers the [Dagger IntelliJ Plugin](https://github.com/square/dagger-intellij-plugin) which does exactly what you ask for:

> The Dagger IntelliJ plugin creates visual connections between an `@Inject` object and the `@Provides` method that creates it.

Note that the plugin is designed for Dagger 1 so if it does work in Dagger 2 [it's merely by accident](https://github.com/square/dagger-intellij-plugin/issues/16#issuecomment-137536885).

Comment: yah i know of this plugin. i tried it in android studio 2.0 but its still not working on dagger2.